# Overlaying an item on top of something with display: table-cell and min-height

Tags: html, css

When using `display: table-cell` it's not possible to give that element `position:relative`. So in order to overlay the entire element with something (e.g a translucent div) you first have to wrap the contents in a div with `position:relative` and then put the overlay inside there.

But when I set a minimum height on the wrapper too then the overlay doesn't extend to the full height and I can't seem to find a way to make the wrapper's contents height-aware. Is there away, using just css, to have a 100% height overlay on  top of a div with display:table-cell and minimum height?

```
<div style="table-row">
    <div style="table-cell; min-height: 100px">
        <div style="position: relative; height: 100%;"> // this refuses to extend to 100% height when the table row forces the cell height to grow
             <p> content </p>
             <div style="position:absolute; top:0;left:0;height:100%;width:100%"> // ... therefore so does this
             </div>
         </div>
    </div>
    <div style="table-cell; height: 150px"></div> // forces the entire row to grow in height
</div>
```